# Android Get Country of Google Play store current app has been downloaded from

Tags: android, sdk, accountmanager, google-play

I need to get the country(in app) which PlayStore is set to upon downloading my app.  I only need to get this value on first launch upon installing my app after download from the playstore.

If not is there a way to derive a country from an Account retrieved through AccountManager?

I have searched around and not yet found a solution.
Thank you so much for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Account does not give you country information. Even if you connect the user to Google+.  You need to use location from network, gps, or since you just need the country, use mcc from the telephony.